# How to get the answer to exact bits using double in android

Tags: java, android, double, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

I have made a Calculator app on android but whenever I do some multiplication of the kind:

```
23.3 x 3.3
```

The answer I get is something like:

```
76.988999999999
```

Now please tell me how to resolve this conflict with this app. The answer should be like

```
76.89
```

Comment: Please clear your question.

Comment: If you want exact arithmetic: Do not use `float` or `double`.

Comment: _What should i use to eliminate this?_ Eliminate what? How do you want the result to look?

Comment: @MrSmith42: It depends on what kind of exact you want. You'd have a similar problem if you used `BigDecimal` and tried `10 / 3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to the world of [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985). In this particular case, you can get a better result with [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) rather than `double`:

```
import java.math.*;

public class BigCheck {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("23.3");
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("3.3");
        System.out.println(a.multiply(b));
    }
}
```

...but `BigDecimal` has its own issues (for instance, try `10 / 3`). But it's probably a better choice for a calculator app, just keep in mind that when dividing, you'll probably need to use [the version that accepts a scale and rounding mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal,%20int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29). And be sure to read the details of the class so you understand its concept of scale.

Comment: it is not working for me. Say i am taking 2 double variables c & d and allowing the user to enter the values using Scanner class, then replacing "23.3" & "3.3" in your example with "c" & "d" resp. then the answer comes out to be: 76.88999999999999820587959220574690445766638900334550912342955475420325228697038
255631923675537109375

Comment: Now tell me what should i use?

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal: I *did* tell you: Use `BigDecimal`, not `double`. If you have `double` in there (anywhere), you will run into the inaccuracies inherent in IEEE-754 floating point. IEEE-754 is designed for speed and sacrifices some accuracy to achieve it. The classic example is `0.1 + 0.2`, which in IEEE-754 results in `0.30000000000000004`. `BigDecimal` is designed for accuracy when doing decimal calculations, at the expense of speed.

Comment: i did explore this and found the way to using it. I actually wanted to take the input from the user so there comes that double, then making it a String, i can pass it it BigDecimal and the problem solved. thanks for the help

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal: If you're taking the input from the user, why not just accept it as a string in the first place? Don't pass it through `double` first, that will introduce the inaccuracies.

Comment: yep! you are right. I think my approach was wrong. thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear. I guess you want to get the exact digits answer.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
String result = df.format(76.988999999999);
```

### EDIT

Example to learn this Decimal Format.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[])  
    {
        double b = 756.988999999999;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
        String result = df.format(b);
        System.out.printf(result);  
    }
}
```

Comment: but i have no idea what the user will enter and if the answer would be 123.4567 then? so i how can i define the format before?

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal I have edited the answer. Now it will suitable your requirement.